# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate installation error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I try to install Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on my laptop, I get this error:

---

Setup Failed!
Install cannot continue because some required components failed.

Please correct the following problems and restart the setup to ensure full product functionality. To learn more, you can review the list of common issues and workarounds or examine the log file.

Setup Engine

### This operation returned because the timeout period expired.

There wasn't anything of relevance in the list of common issues.  In the log file there were these errors:

[0AA8:0FC4][2013-10-20T18:24:54]e000: Error 0x800705b4: Failed to wait for child to connect to pipe.
[0AA8:0FC4][2013-10-20T18:24:54]e000: Error 0x800705b4: Failed to connect to elevated child process.
[0AA8:0FC4][2013-10-20T18:24:54]e000: Error 0x800705b4: Failed to actually elevate.
[0AA8:0FC4][2013-10-20T18:24:54]e000: Error 0x800705b4: Failed to elevate.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

We ran into this same issue this morning (with VS Premium 2013). The user was not a local administrator on their machine, which was causing the problem. Giving them **local admin rights** (or **running the install as administrator**) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look here [Known Issues for Visual Studio 2013](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2890846/en-us). Otherwise you can email them directly. Also remember to start the installer as an administrator. Also run windows update to make sure you have latest version of windows 8 or 8.1.

Comment: Not directly helpful, sorry about this comment.